# Project planing support in JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am looking for project planing support in **JIRA**. An upcoming project contains different work streams which can be quite independent of each other. For each work stream the corresponded tickets will be stored in JIRA.

Assuming that for each ticket the effort estimation in days is derived. I am looking for the following visualization:

> WS1: Ticket_1_1 Ticket_1_2 Ticket_1_3 ...
>
> WS2: Ticket_2_1 Ticket_2_2 Ticket_2_3 ...
>
> ....
>
> WSN: Ticket_N_1 Ticket_N_2 Ticket_N_3 ...

Accompanied by the calendar time axis.

The representation will be used for the definition of implementation order and challenging of project timelines (or ticket descoping)

Does JIRA support such or similar visualizations (may be through plugins)?
Could you please provide some suitable ideas?

Best,

Answer (score 0):

you may try Portfolio for Jira. 
Example: https://www.teamlead.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=18514705
HTH

Answer (score 0):

JIRA is available for rich visualization and reporting functions as it widely uses in the industry. JIRA dashboards and visual boards make better sense in the data-driven approaches. This may help you to have a better discussion on JIRA reportings [HERE](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/reporting-in-jira-461504615.html).
Let me recommend some sort of tools you may be helped in this context. [ZOHO](https://www.zoho.com/) , [ASANA](https://asana.com/home?utm_expid=.5Vei3MMKRWq4PUVVS92Z8w.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F)